# Python method is not returning an node object for red black tree

Tags: python, oop, data-structures, runtime-error, red-black-tree

I'm implementing a Red Black Tree in Python. I have two classes, RedBlackTree and TreeNode. `__setitem__` is defined outside of the code shown below.

The problem with my code is that when I attempt to add the key `-1` to my tree a TreeNode object is created inside the `_put` method, but the object is not properly returned. The caller method 'put' receives no object.

The code works for adding keys `5` and `2`, but for some reason a TreeNode object whose key is `-1` cannot be returned in the way that I've attempted below. See the console output at the bottom.

Any help our advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
class RedBlackTree:
  def put(self, key, val):
    if self.root:
        newNode = self._put(key, val, self.root)
        print("put RECEIVED ", newNode)
        print("put has newNode, who's key is ", newNode.key, 
              " and parent's key is ", newNode.parent.key)
        self.rbInsertFixup(newNode)
    else: # there is no root
        self.root = TreeNode(key, val, parent = self.sentinal, 
                             left = self.sentinal,
                             right = self.sentinal)
        newNode = self.root
        self.rbInsertFixup(newNode)

  def _put(self, key, val, currentNode):
    if key < currentNode.key:
        if currentNode.leftChild != self.sentinal:
            self._put(key, val, currentNode.leftChild)
        else: # currentNode has no child
            newNode = TreeNode(key, val, parent = currentNode, 
            left = self.sentinal, right = self.sentinal )
            currentNode.leftChild = newNode
            print("_put RETURNS ", newNode)
            return newNode
    else: # symetric to THEN clause above, with 'left' chnaged to 'right'
    ...
class TreeNode():
  def __init__(self, key, val, 
             left = None, right = None, 
             parent = None, color = 'red'):
    self.key = key
    self.payload = val
    self.leftChild = left
    self.rightChild = right
    self.parent = parent
    self.color = color
    ...
t = RedBlackTree()
t[5] = 'five'
t[2] = 'two'
t[-1] = 'negative one'
```

Console Output Below...

```
('_put RETURN ', <__main__.TreeNode instance at 0x106bd45a8>)
('put RECEIVED ', <__main__.TreeNode instance at 0x106bd45a8>)
("put has newNode, who's key is ", 2, " and parent's key is ", 5)
('_put RETURN ', <__main__.TreeNode instance at 0x106bd45f0>)
('put RECEIVED ', None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RB-Tree.py", line 383, in <module>
    t[-1] = 'negative one'
  File "RB-Tree.py", line 105, in __setitem__
    self.put(k, v)
  File "RB-Tree.py", line 35, in put
    print("put has newNode, who's key is ", newNode.key, " and parent's     key is ", newNode.parent.key)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'key'
```

`

Comment: After further testing I have a feeling that the problem here has to do with my recursive call to _put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return value is not stored in this `if` clause

```
if currentNode.leftChild != self.sentinal:
    self._put(key, val, currentNode.leftChild)
```

Changed it to

```
if currentNode.leftChild != self.sentinal:
    newNode = self._put(key, val, currentNode.leftChild)
    return newNode
```

Problem solved.